# unable to run node.js on Android phone?

Tags: android, node.js, installation

I have been trying to port Node.js  on Android phone 
by following the link below

http://www.xydo.com/toolbar/20311835-node_js_on_android

I created the node.tar on QEMU environment and sent it to the ubuntu machine ?

I have put all .so files in system/lib and node bin file in system/bin .
When i try to run it it gives "Node not Found " even though it is present .

NOTE : I have manually pushed the files since tar command does not work on android . 
 I am using a rooted device .

Is there any way to create the binary file in android directly without the  ARM environment ???

Am i missing something ?Thanks for the help .

---

Thanks for the response .

I have installed debian on Android using your suggested link:
http://lanrat.com/android/debian

After that, when I run the following commands on chroot to be able to make and install Node js, (ref:http://howtonode.org/f1932c1c56d3a50fe0c21998362d80f405229b5a/arm-chroot-fun)

```
$git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git
$. nvm/nvm.sh              
$export JOBS=1        
$nvm install v0.4.11
```

I get the following error:
/.nvm/src/node-v0.4.11/deps/v8/src/arm/macro-assembler-arm.cc:61:3: error: #error "For thumb inter-working we require an architecture which supports blx"
scons: *** [obj/release/arm/macro-assembler-arm.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Waf: Leaving directory `/.nvm/src/node-v0.4.11/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2): 
    {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}

Alternately, if I try the following:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.11.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf node-v0.4.11.tar.gz
```

Added  '-march=armv5t' to 'CCFLAGS',in node-v0.4.11/deps/v8/SConstruct and the

```
$ cd node-v0.4.11
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

the installation runs without errors, node --version reports v0.4.11 and when I try to run any node commands, I get pure virtual method called terminate called without an active exception Aborted

can you please let me know what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please update this question, don't ask a new one if you're not getting any responses. Perhaps offer a bounty?

Comment: All information on this page is outdated. I am investigating current [viable options to running NodeJS on Android](Aug 2017)].(https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely have tar on your phone and everything else that comes with busybox!
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox 
 Also look at this it will improve your Droid hacking time 10 fold 
 https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions
and consider acquiring 
 http://www.magicandroidapps.com/wiki//index.php?title=Main_Page
 and https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard   Your going to wonder how you where doing it before you got these.
 The tutorial you where following was a little shaky so I included the resources I used to get ubuntu and nodejs running on my Android. It took me a while but it was a lot easier after a little research on how exactly debootstrap and qemu worked, you have to get a little linuxy but once its running you will be amazed at all the options you have.
 http://lanrat.com/android/debian
 http://howtonode.org/f1932c1c56d3a50fe0c21998362d80f405229b5a/arm-chroot-fun 
 What I ended up doing was building a cross compilation tool kit using deb boot strap and qemu and compiling everything on my desktop then moving the image over to my Android.
 Lastly I included my arm ubuntu Image. You may have to tweak the bash script a bit but other then that the image is universal and even runs on an IPhone. If you have any trouble digesting all this or getting the image working feel free to ask. I want to see node on as many phones as possible! 
  [www.castedspell.com/ubuntu4droid.tar.gz](http://castedspell.com/ubuntu4droid.tar.gz) 
 The image is 3 gigs uncompressed but really only 600 mb and you can use any partition re-size tool to shrink it down.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [Android port of NodeJS](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode) with source you can get up and running with.